# Date Picker error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use Jquery Date picker functionality. It is working flawlessly if i am trying to use it a new html file, but while i am trying to integrate it with existing pages of my project it throws errors :

I saw lot of answers where people said jquery may be included twice or order might be incorrect . But all these things looks fine to me , still getting these java-script errors.

I tried to include this file :

```
<script  src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

These are the errors i am facing :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectstart' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker'
```

Please find it here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkr5L/)

Does jquery main file version has impact on this ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: post your html and javascript where you have initialized the datepicker. or set up a fiddle

Comment: I just had something similar happen when I added a reference to the complete jquery UI package-- my site already had a reference to just the datepicker js files.  jquery allows you to build a custom set of features, but it does cause minor issues like this.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: can you post your HTML part and datepicker definition part of jquery ..

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, I see errors relating to jQuery being undefined.  On your site, have you also included the main jQuery library?

Comment: @Paddy : Yes jquery main library is already included

Comment: Is your main jquery lib defined before jquery ui?

Comment: Yes main jquery is before juqery ui

Comment: Post you code. At least the `<head>` part. There must be something fishy going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your code, so we can help you in detail.

Your problem should be, that you want to use an element as a datepicker, but you did not activate the datepicker for that element before.

Example: you want to ask $('#from_monthly') for some property that is used in a datepicker, but you forgett to add code like this

```
 $('#from_monthly').datepicker(...)
```

Or you or the framework want to work with that object but the object was "null"

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectstart' of undefined
```

Comment: Cannot set property 'selectstart' of undefined  this is coming after including jquery ui file